# Deploying ROR application to Linode.com using Capistrano 3.1 from Bitbucket repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, bitbucket, linode

There is ROR application, hosted on Linode.com, source code is hosted on Bitbucket.org. For deploying my ROR app Capistrano 3.1 is used. When I execute following command:

> cap production git:check

everything is fine, connection can be established, but when I try to call

> cap production deploy

it returns error when fetching from origin

```
Command: cd /home/user/app/repo && /usr/bin/env git remote update
Fetching origin
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem after installing SSH client and server, setting up security keys. Great utility, which can be used to diagnose SSH problems is https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor thanks for creator! Cheers.